# I'm dealling with a file:output.txt by shell But I don't know why my code can't read the first line

Tags: linux, shell

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, here is my code:

```
while read line
do
    awk '{split($0,a,",");print a[6],"qid:"NR,"1:"a[1],"2:"a[2],"3:"a[3],"4:"a[4],"5:"a[5]}'
done < output.txt
```

My output.txt is:

```
0.24056906798291974,0.2640402789853635,-0.15613242425814397,0.27656222925649837,0.24663378435409408,0
-0.16397532884934443,-0.08192444714849861,-0.07868578524120746,-0.13202790903354927,-0.5865884600854129,2
```

and so on

and my output is

```
qid:1 1:-0.16397532884934443 2:-0.08192444714849861 3:-0.07868578524120746 4:-0.13202790903354927 5:-0.5865884600854129
qid:2 1:-0.6359437918203192 2:-0.8776433172563813 3:-0.2684300508327019 4:-0.7212267316402121 5:0.24663378435409408
qid:3 1:0.10572093570549834 2:0.09105791591843243 3:-0.1445154284056035 4:0.024894390454657443 5:0.24663378435409408
```

The first line has disappeared. I can't find out why, any ideas?

Comment: please format you question a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read line; do
    awk '{...}'
done < output.txt
```

You're first using `read line` to have the shell read one line of input.
After that happens, you're running `awk` with no filename or redirection, so it reads from the same input. `awk` reads until the end of the file, exits, the loop repeats, and since the input file is at the end, the next `read` returns a false value and the loop breaks.

What you probably want is to just let `awk` read the file itself:

```
awk '{...}' output.txt
```

Comment: OMG  I solve this problem by using your suggestion !!!!,  This problem had troubled me 3 days ... Thank you very much!! (I am the noob in shell)